# PyCharm CTRL+SHIFT+F10 not working on Windows after Upgrade

Tags: pycharm

I just upgraded to PyCharm 21.3 on Windows 10 and CTRL+SHIFT+F10 no longer works to run the current file. How do I restore this functionality please?

Comment: In settings? I have new PyCharm, and Ctrl+Shift+F10 is used by 6 items).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This can help if you want to restore the default settings

for more refer [here!!](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html)

Comment: Restoring default setting is usually bad. One lost customization. It is just last resort.

Comment: are you using the community edition in pycharm? the reason I am asking, that i have faced many bugs like this, usually, I take a backup of the settings and reinstall pycharm and restore the backup which makes the issues go away. if that's ok, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the Key Binding is shadowed by another program?

I used HotkeyDetector referenced here [HotkeyDetector on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows#1204019) and found out, that SnagitCapture was intercepting many hotkeys including SHIFT + F10.